# How to Update data in MongoDb with Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

Hello every one i am working working on mongoDB with java. I done connection insert and retrieve value from mongoDB successfully but when i try to update data then my code is not working .

my code is :

```
public static Result updateprofile() throws UnknownHostException 
{
    final  DynamicForm profileform=form().bindFromRequest();
    final  String username1 = profileform.get("username");
    final  String password1 = profileform.get("password");
    final  String email1 = profileform.get("email");
    final  String userid = session("userid");
    MongoClient mongo=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);

    DB db = mongo.getDB("webportal"); 
    DBCollection coll=db.getCollection("userdb");
    BasicDBObject doc2=new BasicDBObject("_id", userid);
    BasicDBObject doc1=new BasicDBObject();
    doc1.append("username", username1);
    doc1.append("username", username1);
    doc1.append("password", password1);
    doc1.append("email",email1 );
    BasicDBObject doc3=new BasicDBObject("$set",doc1);
    coll.update(doc2, doc3);
    return ok(userid+username1);        
}
```

i read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-update-document/) block for updating data in mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could please try this.

```
ObjectId id= new ObjectId("4f693d40e4b04cde19f17205");        
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();        
searchQuery .put("_id", id); 

BasicDBObject updateDocument = new BasicDBObject();
updateDocument .append("$set", new BasicDBObject("username", username1));

coll.update(searchQuery , updateDocument);
```

Comment: thank you so much for answer my question sir but when i use Objectid the it shows me error ??

Comment: I am geting this error [IllegalArgumentException: invalid ObjectId [DcZ8hFlSwfwylUP5jG6L]]

Comment: and one thing more when i see the id in mongo documentation then i see one api com.mongodb.ObjectId and when i try to import it then its not import in my project ??

Comment: import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

Comment: i import this package and again i run my code but still having the same error . I am using String variable for get value from id is there problem with the string variable in that sir.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35120/discussion-between-simmant-and-shakthydoss)

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
BasicDBObject doc1 = new BasicDBObject();
doc1.append("$set", new BasicDBObject("username", username1)
    .append("password", password1)
    .append("email", email1));
BasicDBObject doc2 = new BasicDBObject("_id", userid);
coll.update(doc2, doc1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer orid i change above code in my my code but problem still same .

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes based on what shakthydoss and orid has given. Here's my solution:

```
MongoClient mongo=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("webportal"); 
DBCollection coll=db.getCollection("userdb");
BasicDBObject doc2 = new BasicDBObject();
doc2.put("_id",userid);
BasicDBObject updateDocument = new BasicDBObject();
updateDocument .append("$set", new BasicDBObject("username", username1).append("password", password1).append("email", email1));
coll.update(doc2, updateDocument);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoTemplate, then directly send your java POJO object (which will have mongoID in it)
for ex: Object to be updated will be

```
{
   "id":"16 digit mongodb autogenerated id",
    "name":"something",
    "age":"something"
}
```

suppose you want to update this,
create pojo class in Java with all above three fields, and send..

and in DAO,
simple do,

```
this.mongoTemplate.save(objectOfPojoType);
```

Since your object contains mongoID which is already present in mongoDB,
so it will update even with save method, rather than creating new one